# Two DNS names for single jfrog artifactory instance

Tags: artifactory

We have a requirement to use two dns names(each with corresponding .pem and .key) for single jfrog artifactory instance.

Tried following the https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/HTTP+Settings, but the setting allows only one public server name. Any suggestions on how to have two public server name each with their own .pem and .key for single jfrog artifactory instance.

Answer (score 2):

To support multiple DNS names with JFrog platform with a **reverse proxy,** adding `X-JFrog-Override-Base-Url` Header will forward the Base URL into the JFrog platform, then Artifactory will use it for building the response.

e.g. for Nginx, you can add

`proxy_set_header  X-JFrog-Override-Base-Url https://$host;`